# Calculating the probability of an intersection

Tags: probability

I have the following *Venn Diagram*,
Let:

- $\color{red}A$ be the red circle
- $\color{blue}B$ be the blue circle
- $\color{green}C$ be the green circle

[image: venn diagram]

I know that $\dfrac{1}{6} = P(\text{(all three)}=x|\text{at least two}) = \dfrac{P(\text{at least two} \cap \text{all three})}{P(\text{at least two})}$ but all if know is $P(\text{at least two})$. How do I find the intersection of *all three* and *at least two* in order to find $x$?

Comment: Is this correct, numbers-wise? The $0.5$ on the outside of all three, along with the $0.4,0.1,0.1,0.15$ total to more than 1. Or are these numbers not probabilities?

Comment: 0.05 instead of 0.5 for the outside part?

Comment: @Did : Yes, that would make it all add to 1. Must be a typo by OP, who should respond if so...

Comment: @Did, a typo indeed. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your diagram, at least 2 is $0.4+0.0+x+(0.2-x)=0.6$. Also note that the intersection of "at least 2" with "all three" is the same as simply "all three", denoted $x$ in your diagram. So you know that $1/6=x/0.6$ from which you get $x=1/10=0.1.$

NOTE: This all assumes the numbers in the venn diagram are probabilities directly. However they add to more than 1, and this all might need adjustment if the OP says the numbers are just "raw numbers" in the regions, not denoting probabilities. (I await confirmation by OP on this issue.)

***As Did suggests in his comment, if that outer number were a typo and should have been $0.05$ then things add to 1 properly, and no need to adjust

Comment: indeed a typo, sorry for that.